# Importing android existing project

Tags: android

I am trying to import android existing project but it gives the warning 'No Project are found to import'. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new project and choose: "Android Project From Existing Source"

Then select the folder of that project

Answer (score 0):

do you changed your workspace? if so, copy the folder of the project to your new workspace folder, then import..